# Given n objects. Finding the number of rows and columns in the most compact way.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Given a set of $n$ objects that need to be arranged in a row-column format, how can I find the rows and columns such that they are the most compact?

For example, if I have $5$ items, the most compact way would be $3$ rows by $2$ columns or $2$ rows by $3$ columns.

If I had $9$ items, this would be $3$ rows by $3$ columns.

I have been working with a simple formula that I found,

```
N = number of items

Rows = floor(sqrt(N))
Columns = N / Rows
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're trying to make the most "square" representation, then it seems that taking the square root of $n$ is the easiest way of doing it. If $n$ doesn't have a perfect square, then $\sqrt(n)$ falls within two consecutive integers, $x$, $x+1$, which will be the lengths of the rows/columns, depending on which one you choose.

Comment: @scoopfaze That is not quite the whole story; if $\sqrt{n}> x+\frac12$, then you need to use $x+1$ rows and $x+1$ columns. E.g. when $n=7$, so $\sqrt{7}\approx 2.64$, you need $3$ rows and $3$ columns (or $4$ rows and $2$ columns).

Comment: certainly fixed though when looking at possibilities we note $x^2$ too small, $(x+1)^2$ certainly big enough, so take $\lceil \frac{n}{x+1}\rceil$ for the second number.

Comment: @MikeEarnest, you're right; I was too hasty in my calculations. It certainly seems that for $\sqrt n$ which leaves a remainder of larger than $.5$, you need to use $(x+1)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined how “compactness” is measured. I will assume the compactness of an arrangement is the number of rows it spans, plus the number of columns it spans. This penalizes long, skinny arrangements in favor of roughly square ones.

If you use $r$ rows and $c$ columns, then it must be true that $rc\ge n$. The Cauchy-Schqarz inequality then implies $r+c\ge 2\sqrt{rc}\ge 2\sqrt{n}$, so you need at least $\lceil 2\sqrt n \rceil$ rows and columns and total.

This is always achievable. There are two cases.

- If $\lceil 2\sqrt n \rceil$ is even, then $\frac12\lceil 2\sqrt n \rceil$ rows and columns are sufficient, as
  $$
  (\tfrac12\lceil 2\sqrt n \rceil)^2\ge (\tfrac12 (2\sqrt n))^2 = n
  $$
- If $\lceil 2\sqrt n \rceil$ is odd, then $\frac12(\lceil 2\sqrt n \rceil+1)$ rows and $\frac12(\lceil 2\sqrt n \rceil-1)$ columns are sufficient, as 
  $$
  \tfrac12(\lceil 2\sqrt n \rceil+1)\cdot \tfrac12(\lceil 2\sqrt n \rceil-1)=\tfrac14\big(\lceil 2\sqrt n \rceil^2-1\big)\ge \tfrac14 \big((2\sqrt{n})^2-1\big)=n-\tfrac14
  $$
  Since the LHS is an integer which is $\ge n-\frac14$, it is also $\ge n$.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Under what cases is ⌈2Sqrt(n)⌉ not even?

Comment: @BryanHarrington The $n$ for which $\lceil 2\sqrt{n}\rceil$ is odd are $$2,\;\;5,6,\;\;10,11,12,\;\;17,18,19,20,\;\;\dots,\;\;k^2+1,k^2+2,\dots,k^2+k,\dots$$

Comment: I had an error in my calculation. This looks really good.